# NGRX effect not saving updated state in store

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a boolean setting from our API that we want to cache after it has been called once. Figuring we would need to set the value whenever we added a new instance of `appSettings` (our application-wide settings), I wrote the following effect:

```
  public checkCachedEffectg$ = createEffect(()=>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(addAppSettings),
  withLatestFrom(
    this.store.select(selectAppSettings),
    (store)=> store
  ),
  switchMap((currentState)=> {
    if(currentState.isSettingPositiveSet){
      return of(currentState);
    }
    return this.settingsService.isSettingPositive()
      .pipe(map(res => {
        currentState.isSettingPositiveSet = true;
        currentState.isSettingPositive = res;
        return currentState;
      }
    ));
  }),
  map(state => {
    return addAppSettingsSuccess(state);
  }),
  catchError(this.errorHandler.handleError)
```

));

The effect seems to work in that if the value is already set, it returns the cached data and if the value has not been set, it goes and fetches it from the API. What doesn't seem to work is updating the NGRX store. Even though the returned state has the new values, any future calls to the state just return the original `AppSettings` and not the one that was produced by the above code.

Am I going about this the right way? Is there some additional call I have to make in order to get the state to reflect the value of the updated `currentState` property?

Comment: It looks like you are returning a reference to the old state. Try returning an updated copy of the state.

Comment: `return {…currentState, isSettingPositiveSet: true,  isSettingPositive: res}`

Comment: That doesn't seem to change the situation. The state still reports the settings unchanged in the next select

Comment: You have reducer listening to `addAppSettingsSuccess`?

Comment: I do, but its just passing the newState along

Comment: Edit: Turns out I had reducers for everything but addAppSettingsSuccess, which was accidently a second copy of loadAppSettingsSuccess. Added the reducer and now things cache properly

Answer (score 0):

You are using ngrx wrong, which might lead to some unexpected sideeffects. Everything in the map operator of `isSettingPositive` pipe should be handled by a reducer. Never change the state within an effect.

Also, you will never run into the if block.

```
withLatestFrom(
    this.store.select(selectAppSettings),
    (store)=> store
  ),
```

`withLatestFrom` operator creates you an array of data. Following those lines you wrote

```
switchMap((currentState)=> {
    if(currentState.isSettingPositiveSet){
```

That means `currentState` is an array, where you call `isSettingPositiveSet` on. That will never be `true`.

Comment: The reducer mapping turned out to be the missing piece, but I'm new to NGRX and want to to do things in pattern if possible. Can you link to an article or documentation about doing this in the reducer?

Comment: https://dev.to/this-is-angular/ngrx-tips-i-needed-in-the-beginning-4hno#create-reusable-reducers